# How exactly does Normal Force work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I just want to get a doubt of mine clear. So when I chuck a ball with a force $\vec F$ at a wall, to prevent them from going through each other, and in accordance with Newton's Third Law, the wall will exert a force $-\vec F$ on the ball, and here the normal forces are $\vec F$ and $-\vec F$? I.e., the normal forces are, in any case, an action force, and the corresponding reaction force?

Comment: The force you apply to the ball and the force the wall exerts on the ball are not an action-reaction (Newton 3rd law) pair.  The force you apply to the ball and the force the ball applies to your hand  is an action-reaction pair.  The force the ball applies to the wall and the force the wall applies to the wall is the other action-reaction pair.

Answer (score 0):

> I chuck a ball with a force $\vec F$ at a wall

For how long or how far? The wall will always take a shorter time and almost no distance in this bouncing, and thus will always have a totally different force in reply. The time integral of the force you supply is the momentum $\vec p=m\vec v=\int\vec F\mathrm dt$ given to the ball, and the length integral $E=\frac12mv^2=\int\vec F\cdot\mathrm d\vec x$ is the energy given to the ball; if you know one, and you know the mass, then you can find out what actually is the momentum of the ball.

> in accordance with Newton's Third Law

The wall will, again, exert a force much stronger than your hand or arm. The unequal magnitude means that this two cannot be a N3L pair.

What the wall is doing, is to exchange momentum with the ball so that the ball flies backwards. This is usually done with almost all the kinetic energy of the ball conserved, but it is possible to just stick to the wall too. We are talking about bouncing, so let us consider the case where kinetic energy is conserved, because it is so much simpler. Then the momentum that the wall gives to the ball is $-2\vec p$, and over a tiny time, the force is quite large.

There is only one momentum interaction. So, the ball is giving $2\vec p$ worth of momentum to the wall. That is the same statement as above. The force version of this is the N3L pair.

---

N3L is a peculiarity of Newton's Force viewpoint. No other part of physics does this accounting stupidity. There is no N3L equivalent to the Conservation of Energy, because we only talk about the one singular interaction event in CoE. When we talk about the singular interaction event in the Conservation of Linear Momentum, then we will not need N3L either. Newton predated an understanding of these theoretical issues, and so he did not realise that he made a bad choice in presentation. Because of that, he had to make accounting credit and debit ledger agreements using N3L.

---

You should also ask about how the wall actually exerts a force at all. The wall is resisting bending, and so is the ball. It is that, that is the normal force.